# How to convert JSON body to text in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to create a string property containing the JSON I'm sending in the body.

The problem is that if I send the json with the header 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', perfect. But if I send it with 'Content-Type': 'application/json' I think it tries to convert it to xml.

This is for a Linux server, wso2 EI 6.4.0

this is the JSON that I'm sending:
`{ "hello": "isJson" }`

and with the header Content-Type: 'application/json' in the string I get only this: isJson

but when I make the request with Content-Type: 'text/plain' the result is this: {"hello": "isJson"}.

How can I get the same result with Content-Type: application/json?

Thanks

Comment: `I get only this: isJson` - where you get it? how?

Comment: when the message arrives, I put this property to convert the message to text <property name = "messageType" value = "text/plain" scope="axis2" /> but seeing that it has the body after changing the property it looks like this: isJson

Answer (score 1):

This happens because EI represents the payload in XML format internally. 
When you invoke using text/plain EI put it inside two 'text' tags as follows

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">{ "hello": "isJson" }</text></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note that { "hello": "isJson" } is preserved.

When you invoke using application/json EI converts it to XML as follows

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonObject><hello>isJson</hello></jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

When you enrich body to property two different representations get enriched to the body as represented above.

We did some improvements to this message flow by introducing native JSON support to Enrich mediator. You can get the expected behaviour from the upcoming release EI 6.5.0.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick response. in the end I solved the problem with a payloadFactory indicating Media Type: text and in args I have set $. (all the json)